# Recovering connection with the database

Tags: c#, sql-server

guys! I've accidentally deleted the connection to database from Server Explorer. It's any chance to get the connection back? The instance name is `(LocalDB)\v11.0`. I've tried to add connection by typing to the database file name `(LocalDB)\v11.0` and the program said:

> Attempted to access a path that is not on the disk.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the question! I've did some research before and I didn't found out anything useful, in my case.

PS: If I'm trying to create a database on Server `(LocalDB)\v11.0`with the same name, it shows that the database already exists.

Comment: Are you using source control lke Git, TFS ?

Comment: No. Isn't any way to get the path to the database to reconnect?

Comment: I've tried to add a database on the server `(LocalDB)\v11.0` with the same name of the earlier database and it shows that the database already exists, so I should find it somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sqllocaldb.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017) commandline tool to manage your localdb instances.
To view the current instances simply type

```
sqllocaldb info
```

To start an instance called v11.0 type

```
sqllocaldb start v11.0
```

You can also create, stop, delete, etc. using this tool.
If your database is broken for whatever reason, you can find the masterdb of the localdb instance here

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local
>   DB\Instances

Just delete the whole folder to remove the instance. You can then recreate it.
If you would like to debug possible errors instead you can also use the masterdb found there and hook into a sqlserver express instance or another localdb for inspection.

Note that this location only contains the masterdb but the actual database files are stored in

> C:\Users\USERNAME\

by default. So if you detached a database you can reattach it by looking for a database stored at that path.
If you would like to connect to a localdb instance, the connection string is always

```
(LocalDB)\NAME
```

But a shared localdb instance has a slightly different connection string:

```
(LocalDB)\.\SHAREDNAME
```